# Eliminating " character R

Tags: r, formatting

I used the sprintf function to format numbers.

Something like this

```
    sprintf("%08.2f", 86.30)

    [1] "00086.30"
```

but in a data structure

```
    Pre$valor <- sprintf("%08.2f", Pre$valor)
```

And then, I wrote a table using write.table, but I need to eliminate the " characters conserving the format.

I tried

```
    str_replace_all(Pre, "[^[:alnum:]]", "")
    write.table(Pre, "C:/Documents and Settings/test.bna", sep="  ", row.names = FALSE)
```

but it doesn't work

Any ideas?

Comment: `write.table` has a `quote` argument.

Comment: nice, so simple ! Thanks